# Docusign: how to use multiple conditional parents for 1 text tab via SOAP API?

Tags: docusignapi

I need to add tabs for a recipient via the Docusign SOAP API and have the following question:
1. Is there a way to support multiple conditional parents for 1 text tab? For example, selecting a radio button for 1 question or selecting a checkbox on a different question would make the same text field visible. If so, what do I need to do in the tabs structure to support this?

Answer (score 0):

To configure DocuSign tabs as conditional you need to set the `conditionalParentLabel` to the tab that controls its visibility and the `conditionalParentValue` to the value you are checking for.

The `conditionalParentLabel` points to a single tab, so you can not have the conditional aspect controlled to more than one tab.  However you can waterfall the conditional checks to add multiple ones, for example:

Parent Tab 1 -> Parent Tab 2 -> tab you want to hide/show